# Prestashop 1.7 hook on admin product

Tags: module, hook, product, prestashop-1.7

I have a error on my custom module.
I need to put a extra text on product admin page.
I have use the hook "hookDisplayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle", and it display my tpl with the info (on the image, it is the text "Información adicional relacionada").

[image]

The problem is, when the module is active the product admin page not finish of charge.

[image]

So I can't save the product or do anything.

This is the code of the hook

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle($params) 
{
    $product = new Product($params['id_product']);
        
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'product ' => $product,
        )
    );
    return $this->display($this->_path, '/views/templates/admin/admininfo.tpl');
}
```

If I comment only the line "return ....", of course it doesn't display, but the product page charge properly.

On the tpl I write only a text, I don't put yet even a variable.

The other code seems to works properly. I have commented the javascript code on my module.
Nor errors or warnings on the console or even on logs.
I have actived the debbug mode, but not even there display any error.

Any idea or suggest will be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :

```
$tpl = $this->context->smarty->createTemplate(
        dirname(__FILE__).'/views/templates/admin/yourtemplate.tpl'
    );
```

And then :

```
return $tpl->fetch();
```

Comment: No, still remain the same problem :( But thank you anyway! ;)

Comment: Well, this is weird. Double-check your TPL content as this looks a smarty compilation issue to me... You can try a simple "echo" inside the hook instead of returning the template to troubleshoot this

Comment: You're right! I thought something similar, and tried to put only html in the tpl (without variables). And actually the problem was not the variables. In the tpl I put only html, and it has a form, and that caused the error.
Thank you very much for your time!